# What is the idiomatic way in rust for a function accepts a closure as argument or return a closure?

Tags: rust

What is the idiomatic way in rust for a function accepts a closure as argument or return a closure?

I see it can be done in at least the below 3 ways:

```rust
// 1
pub fn run_with_envs_guard1(envs: &HashMap<&str, &str>, f: &dyn FnOnce()) {}

// 2
pub fn run_with_envs_guard2(envs: &HashMap<&str, &str>, f: Box<dyn FnOnce()>) {}

// 3
pub fn run_with_envs_guard3<F: FnOnce()>(envs: &HashMap<&str, &str>, f: F) {}
```

Are there really some differences among these 3 ways? If yes, pls help to clarify, and which way is more idiomatic i should choose?

I am learning rust still, sorry if all the above ways are some bad/strange things.

---

Maybe a more specific question, why in way `1` and `2` i need the `dyn` keyword, but in `3` i don't, from my understanding, these all need dynamic dispatching, is it? as the actual function cannot be determined in compiling time

Comment: In the standard library the 3rd is very common. E.g. [Option::unwrap_or_else<F>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else)

Comment: Note that the 2nd option doesn't make much sense when _accepting_ a closure, because it unnecessarily forces an allocation. (The 1st form also accommodates a `Box` if the caller has one, because `&f` will produce the required reference.)

Answer (score 3):

Abdul answers the first half of your question (and I agree completely with what he said), so I'll take a stab at the second half.

If you want to return a closure from a function, you can't return a type parameter, because that implies that you're returning an instance of *any* `FnOnce`, at the caller's choice. You can't return a `&FnOnce`, because you (usually) need to pass ownership to the caller. You could make it work with `Box<FnOnce>`, but that tends to just be clunky to work with. When returning closures from functions, I'm partial to the [`impl` trait syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html).

```
pub fn test() -> impl FnOnce() {
  || { println!("It worked!") }
}
```

In argument position, writing `impl FnOnce()` as the type of something is equivalent to defining a type argument, as Abdul did in his answer. However, in return position, it's an entirely new feature that returns an opaque value. It says "I'm returning an `FnOnce`, and I'm not telling you which one it is". It's the same concept as a trait object, but without the overhead of throwing it in a box.

---

Responding to your edit

> i don't, from my understanding, these all need dynamic dispatching, is it? as the actual function cannot be determined in compiling time

This is actually not necessarily true. If you see the `dyn` keyword, then there's definitely a dynamic (runtime) dispatch happening. To understand your other example, though, let's consider a simple trait that doesn't have the baggage of `FnOnce`.

```
pub trait MyTrait {}

struct Foo;
struct Bar;

impl MyTrait for Foo {}
impl MyTrait for Bar {}

pub fn example<T: MyTrait>(_arg: T) {
  println!("It works!");
}

fn main() {
  example(Foo);
  example(Bar);
}
```

I claim there's no dynamic dispatch happening here. Rust *monomorphizes* functions with type parameters. That means that `example` is like a template function in C++. Every instantiation of it will end up being a *separate* function. So, really, during Rust's compilation, this will end up being more like

```
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

pub fn example1(_arg: Foo) {
  println!("It works!");
}

pub fn example2(_arg: Foo) {
  println!("It works!");
}

fn main() {
  example1(Foo);
  example2(Bar);
}
```

Two unrelated functions that happen to do something similar. Rust resolves all of the linkage *statically*, so there's no dispatch happening at runtime. In fact, we can prove it. Take the code I just posted above and compile it with debugging symbols on (`rustc -g filename.rs`). Then use a tool like [`nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) (available on most Linux machines by default) to list all of the symbols in the linker table. Assuming you didn't turn any optimizations on, you should see *two* `example` functions. This is what they look like in my linker

```
0000000000005340 t _ZN10code7example17h46383f9ad372dc94E
00000000000053a0 t _ZN10code7example17h97b400359a146fcaE
```

or, with `nm -C` to demangle the function names

```
0000000000005340 t code::example
00000000000053a0 t code::example
```

Two different functions, each of which takes concrete arguments of specific types.

Your proposed `FnOnce` would work the same way.

```
pub fn run_with_envs_guard3<F: FnOnce()>(envs: &HashMap<&str, &str>, f: F) {}
```

Every closure in Rust has a distinct type, so *every time* this function is called, a new version of `run_with_envs_guard3` will get made, specifically for that closure. That new function will know exactly what to do for the closure you just gave it. In 99% of cases, if you have optimizations turned on, these made-up local functions will get inlined and optimized out, so no harm done. But there's no dynamic dispatch here.

In the other two examples, we have a `dyn FnOnce`, which is more like what you'd expect coming from a traditionally object-oriented language. `dyn FnOnce` contains a dynamic pointer to some function somewhere that will be dispatched at runtime, the way you'd expect.

Comment: Ah I see, even return a closure I can use the impl trait syntax surgar, so I guess it will work also when the returned closure has arguments and return types? BTW could u also help to address the new concern I just added?

Comment: @Inshi Alright, I gave it a go. Give my edited post a read and see if that answers your question. And yes, the `impl trait` syntax sugar works with arguments and return type as well.

Comment: your are right, i researched a bit also, so can ppl assume that whenever the generic type is used `fn name<generic types>(args..)` rustc will do the monomorphization, thus 100% there will NOT be dynamic dispatching at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the third one. Because the [rust documentation suggest](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#) to *Use [`FnOnce` as a bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html#bounds) when you want to accept a parameter of function-like type and only need to call it once*.

```
pub fn run_with_envs_guard3<F: FnOnce()>(envs: &HashMap<&str, &str>, f: F) {}
```

This means that the `F` to be bound by `FnOnce`(ie, `F` must implement `FnOnce`)

Comment: Could u pls help to address the new concern I added also?